# Why does Windows consider a certificate valid even after its expiration time?

Tags: certificates, windows, code-signing, validation, expiration-date

I downloaded Google's Cloud SDK installer today, and upon checking the certificate to validate it, I noticed something strange: the expiration date of the certificate appears to be December 22nd 2019 - over four months from today, April 30th 2020. Despite this, however, Windows displays the certificate as valid and doesn't seem to care that the certificate is past its expiration date.

[image: Screenshot of the certificate details. Notice the expiration date.]

What is happening here, then? Why does Windows consider this certificate valid even though it expired four months ago? I was under the impression that certificates can no longer be trusted after they expire, and require a renewal. Is this not the case with software signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK if the certificate has expired - as long as the timestamped signature on the file that you downloaded was made while the certificate still was valid.

See https://comodosslstore.com/resources/how-to-avoid-code-signing-certificate-expired-issues/ for more info.

Comment: Years ago, I wrote a more complete blog post on this subject: https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx

Comment: @Crypt32 well done.  Thanks for posting the link to this.